# Django Query: Annotating queryset list with Sum of fields Values

Tags: python, django

I have 3 simple models:

```
from django_better_admin_arrayfield.models.fields import ArrayField

class Skill(BaseModel):
    value = models.IntegerField()
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE related_name="skills")

class Item(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class BuildItem(models.Model):
    base = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mandatory_skills = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True), default=list)
```

I would like to have a list of **BuildItem** annotated with the sums of the value field of the **Skill** table, only if the **Skill** id is contained in the **mandatory_skills** field.

To annotate the list of **BuildItem** I have the following query which works:

```
q = BuildItem.objects.annotate(sum_skill=Coalesce(Sum("base__skills__value"), 0))
```

I would also like to add up the **Skills** having an id present in **mandatory_skills**.

I tried many things but without success, does anyone have a solution?